# Elasticsearch not working as expected for 'float' types

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a simple document consisting of a `float` type field holding value `1234.45670023`.

I am making a `match_phrase_prefix` query with `1234.4`, I don't get hits. But if I update my query to `1234.45` I get the result. Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: match_phrase_prefix  can only be used on text field. It will throw error when used on float. Can you share your mapping and query

Comment: This is my document:
{
    "test": 123.456
}

This is my mapping:
{
    "float_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "floats": {
                "properties": {
                    "test": {
                        "type": "float"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: What is your elastic search version. In new version 7.* match_phrase_prefix on float field throws error Can only use phrase prefix queries on text fields - not on [test] which is of type [float]. For float field you can use a range query and define a upper and lower limit